# Meteor filter collection

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to secure accessing a specific collection but I'm having troubles doing it. I have no problems disabling the insert, update and delete with the `Collection.allow()` map.

The problem is that I also want to filter the results returned by the `Collection.find()` and `Collection.findOne()` function. I read about the `Meteor.publish()` and `Meteor.subscribe()` stuff, but somehow I cannot make it work (it's not getting filtered, I just can see all the results).

In my server-code I do the following:

```
Groups = new Meteor.Collection("groups");
Meteor.publish("myGroups", function() {
    if (Functions.isAdmin(userId)) {
        return Groups.find({
            sort: {
                name: 1
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

The function I'm using really works (so it's not that it's always returning `true`).

In the client-code I wrote the following:

```
Meteor.subscribe("myGroups");
Groups = new Meteor.Collection("groups");
```

Now when I do `Groups.find{});` at the client I still get all results (and I should get no result).

Am I misunderstanding something or doing something wrong? I could of course make the collection completely server-side and use `Meteor.methods()` and `Meteor.call()` to get the collection data (so that it's always encapsulated by the server). But I really thought it would be cool that I didn't have to do that.

Also I wonder why this can't be done on the same level as insert/update/remove with `Collection.allow()`. I mean, it would be could that we could have the possibility to add a filter to the map for reading data through find/findOne.

Comment: did you remove autopublish with `meteor remove autopublish`?

Comment: I could bang my head against the wall now. I did now and it works, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Tarang said, removing autopublish by executing the following command works:

```
meteor remove autopublish
```